# Listening to absence of event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

3rd party JS plugin emits an event that can be listened to:

```
jsInt.on('ready', function(services) {
    if(Array.isArray(services) && ~services.indexOf('magic')) {
        //integration is ready to use and it has 'magic' service available
    } else {
        //integration is ready to use but it does not have 'magic' service
    }
});
```

How can I programmatically detect if this event did not occur in 3 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the `on` callback cancel a timeout, where the timeout runs after 3 seconds:

```
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Library did not load in time!');
  // ...handle the problem
}, 3000);

jsInt.on('ready', function(services) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  // rest of the code
  if(Array.isArray(services) && ~services.indexOf('magic')) {
    //integration is ready to use and it has 'magic' service available
  } else {
    //integration is ready to use but it does not have 'magic' service
  }
});
```

Comment: in your suggested way, how do I make sure that the `on` callback doesn't get executed if a library loads after 3 seconds?

Comment: Does the library have an `off` method you can call? (kind of like removeEventListener - it probably does)

Comment: I am not sure. Are you suggesting the `jsInt.off('ready');` inside setTimeout might work?

Comment: Could be, though it's likely you need to pass a reference to the same function. eg `const fn = (services) => ...`, then `jsInt.on('ready', fn)`, and in the timeout, `jsInt.off('ready', fn)` - but that's a wild guess - look up the library docs

Comment: The suggested solution works just fine when combined with `var useInt = true;`, `useInt = false;` inside setTimeout and `if(useInt){}` inside the `on` callback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's what promises are there for.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var timeout = false;
    setTimeout(function() { timeout = true; reject('time-out'); }, 3000);
    jsInt.on('ready', function(services) {
        if (timeout) return;
        if(Array.isArray(services) && ~services.indexOf('magic')) {
            //integration is ready to use and it has 'magic' service available
          resolve("with-magic");
        } else {
          resolve("no-magic");
            //integration is ready to use but it does not have 'magic' service
        }
    });
})
    .then(function(magic) {
        console.log(magic);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

console.log("Not blocking");
```

Comment: Looks like you are relying on setTimeout. Can you explain why wrapping it with a promise is better than using setTimeout alone?